# How to make 1 Combobox only editable if another combobox holds a specific answer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have 2 `ComboBox` on a Form; they both contain "Yes" and "No". How do I make it so that the second `ComboBox` can only be accessed if "No" was selected in the first `ComboBox`?

Comment: A your can edit a combo box based on the `DropDownStyle`. You are looking for the `.Enabled` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() = "No" Then

      ComboBox2.Enabled = True

    Else

      ComboBox2.Enabled = False

    End If

End Sub
```